# Oracle - INSERT statement with generated primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a table with many columns (20 or 25) and i want to build an insert statement on it, using select and generating another primary key

The simple soulution will be:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT mySeq.nextVal PRIMARY_KEY, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4...
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 1
```

Since my table have many columns, there is a way to say "i give you primary key, and ALL the other columns are the same" without explain them?

Like:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT mySeq.nextVal m.* /* Sure this not work because i get again PRIMARY_KEY column*/
  FROM myTable m
 WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 1
```

Comment: You want to duplicate the existing data but with a new key? How is the key usually assigned, manually or through a trigger?

Comment: The key is assigned manyally as i have show on top. I have already my record and i want to duplicate it with (for sure) another key. I want to have all other columns the same value, except the primary key. With the first statement it works, but i have to specify all the columns.

Comment: I am kinda confused. Can you show some example to elucidate your requirement.

Comment: He want a select * except primary key

Comment: Ah, basically the table needs to be normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to specify something like `SELECT * EXCEPT aColumn`, you will have to write them manually as you already did, sorry.

Actually, you could do a subquery that select column from table info then query that subquery but that make non-sense to me.

If your table contains so many column that it is a pain to write them all, then you might want to re-design your database and split your table in multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks... so it was as i suspected.... :-(

Comment: @Mistre83 You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.